# Kotlin properties and weird casting behaviour: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Android Studio was nagging me to update my Kotlin project from 1.3.61 to version 1.4.0, so I did that, but then I got the exception in the title. I ran the code in an emulator with API 29. The code was the equivalent of the following:

```
    val tv : TextView = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText(applicationContext)
    tv.text = "Hello StackOverflow!"
    val s = tv.text.toString()
```

And that exception was caused by the `tv.text.toString()`. I find this weird, because it worked before updating, and as I understand it the code is equivalent to `tv.getText().toString()`. But the latter works, while the former doesn't.

This works as well:

```
   val tv : TextView = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText(applicationContext)
   tv.setText("Hello StackOverflow!")
   val s = tv.text.toString()
```

This also works:

```
    val tv : TextView = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText(applicationContext)
    tv.text = "Hello StackOverflow!"
    val s = (tv.text as CharSequence).toString()
```

Is this correct behaviour? If that is the case, I would appreciate it if someone could explain what is going on.

So to summarise, if I use the Kotlin property syntax `tv.text` for both setting and getting the value, I get the exception. If I explicitly use `tv.getText()` OR `tv.setText()`, it works. Setting and getting the value with `tv.text` can be made to work if I introduce an explicit cast (which I really don't understand why it is needed, as `tv.text` already should return a `CharSequence`).